# Why is the buffer smaller when receiving than from what I am sending?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am currently trying to send a buffer from my client to my server, the buffer I am trying to send is the byte array from a image on my PC.

It says that the size is roughly 200k bytes when sending but I only receives 61k, doesn't matter what picture I send, the receive buffer is always the same, why is this? How do I get the correct buffer from my client to my server?

I need the entire thing so it can download the image once it receives the byte array.

**Client**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace TransferImageClient
{
    class Program
    {
        // Declare a port that we will be using for the TcpClient to connect to
        const int port = 1273;

        // Declare the server IP that TcpClient will be connecting to.
        const string server_ip = "127.0.0.1";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            string texttoSend = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server_ip, port);

            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path to the image: ");

            byte[] bytesToSend = ConvertImage(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Sending image..");

            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
            Console.ReadLine();

            //Close the client so we're not leaving it open for people to eavesdrop.
            client.Close();
        }

        private static byte[] ConvertImage(string Image)
        {
            Bitmap tImage = new Bitmap(Image);
            byte[] bStream = ImageToByte(tImage);
            return bStream;
        }

        static byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap iImage)
        {
            MemoryStream mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return mMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace TransferImageServer
{
    class Program
    {
        const int port = 1273;
        const string serverIP = "127.0.0.1";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            IPAddress localAdress = IPAddress.Parse(serverIP);

            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdress, port);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening..");

            listener.Start();

            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            Console.WriteLine("Recieved the image ");

            Console.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine("Sending back : ");
            //nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            client.Close();
            listener.Stop();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to log the value of `bytesRead`? How big is it? If it is smaller than the size of the image you are trying to receive then you need to do multiple `client.Read` operations in a loop and stop when `bytesRead` becomes 0.

Answer (score 0):

TCP does not have a concept of messages. That means it doesn't care how many bytes you write at once - and that means `Read` won't return the same number of bytes you wrote at once.

`Read` is allowed to return any amount of data, up to the amount that was sent. If you keep calling `Read` over and over you will keep getting more data (as long as there is more data).